# Readline completion tab extra space

Tags: php, command-line-interface, readline

I'm trying to set auto-complete for readline to enable a user to navigate through the filesystem directories when running a script through CLI.

I found out PHP has a function called [`readline_completion_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline-completion-function.php) for this purpose but every time I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete a word, it adds a space at the end.

```
readline_completion_function(function() {
    return ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
});

// Input a or b or c
readline('Add char and tab: ');
```

I've create fiddle for you to test this:
https://repl.it/@rmdev/Readline-Completion-Tab-Extra-Space

I saw on [Python readline configs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/readline.html#readline.set_completer_delims) that there's a configuration called `set_completer_delims` to set a character to be apendend after tab is hit but in PHP there are only [two configurations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/readline.configuration.php) and none of them apply to the completer delims.

I also saw some posts referring to this as a known bug but it seems it has been fixed on most of the integrations although I don't see any reference to a fix for the PHP one.

Is there any way to remove this space?

I'm using PHP 7.2.12 on a Mac.

Comment: I had the same problem and, so far, I was unable to find the solution.  In Windows works fine (cmd and Powershell) but in Linux.